# Linux : Setting which php bin to use in CLI

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, bin

Hi i'm trying to use **php** command in linux. However I have **two installations of php,** one I got from the sudo-apt-get and one from a stack, [Lappstack](https://bitnami.com/stack/lapp). Don't ask how I got there, but nevertheless i'm trying to execute php in CLI .

```
$ php file.php
```

it both works whichever php it points to but I want to use the php that I use in the stack.

**when I try to execute :**

```
$ which php
```

**It returns :**

```
/usr/bin/php
```

**But I have to use the php I have in my lappstack which is in :**

```
/home/userName/lappstack/php/bin
```

**How do I change the php bin that my CLI php points to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `php` in `/usr/bin` by yours like this:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/php
sudo ln -s /home/userName/lappstack/php/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Hope this helps

Comment: keep in mind this is going to change the PHP binary for everything, not just your command line. The proper way would be alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can either have `/home/userName/lappstack/php/bin` first in your `$PATH` or use [`alias`](http://www.linfo.org/alias.html):

> alias php='/home/userName/lappstack/php/bin/php'

Comment: I tried using the alias, it works but when I close my terminal instance and get back to it again. It points to the old php bin. how do I permanently set it? thanks!

Comment: You can set alias permanently by adding it to the file `~/.bashrc` which is executed every time you open a terminal